# Dynamic SOQL Queries and Managed Namespaces

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

If I create a dynamic SOQL query (via strings, to be used with Database.query) in an unmanaged code environment, and then the code is converted to a managed environment, are namespace considerations taken into account?  Or do I need to ensure I've prefixed my managed object names with the namespace of the managed package while assembling the dynamic SOQL query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you create dynamic SOQL queries and then later go to package the code in a managed package, you don't need to consider the prefix in your queries, the platform will magically know that the objects/fields are part of your package (assuming they were) and do the magic for you.

For example, if you had this SOQL in a class:

```
List<SObject> listOfThings = Database.query('Select MyField__c From Things__c');
```

And then eventually converted the package to a managed package with namespace prefix MyPKG you would **not** need to code it as:

```
List<SObject> listOfThings = Database.query('Select MyPKG__MyField__c From MyPKG__Things__c');
```

Comment: But, on the flip side of this coin, if you have a field by a certain name, and it mirrors the same name as an unmanaged field in the organization, your code won't be able to query the unmanaged field by virtue of "shadowing."

Comment: So, I think you're saying if you have managed MyPKG__MyField__c and unmanaged MyField__c on the same object, and you query it dynamically as in the managed package as MyField__c it won't be able to?

Comment: You would only be able to query MyPKG__MyField__c, but MyField__c would not be accessible.

Comment: sfdcfox, do you know a way around this conflict? Are you aware of a salesforce org having a built in namespace much like apex classes have 'system'? so a query agains system__MyField__c would work even though MyPKG__MyField__c also exists? I know the answer is not 'system', but is there another option?

Comment: Can this conflict exist? I know Salesforce stores the field name and the namespce in separate system fields.

Comment: This conflict exists. We have this issue where we are querying two objects that have the same name, one in a managed package and one a customer built. Is there a workaround for when I query in a managed package to force it to use namespace? This is dynamic SOQL issue.

Comment: So, you want to query the object outside the package from within your package, and its querying your object instead of other? Can't you use the fully qualified object name from within your package?

Answer (score 1):

Case 1).
   If the Organization contains Namespace.
   For ex. I have an Object (Object_Analysis__c)  in my Org with namespace(Naveen_catch) , Querying with  or without namespace  makes no difference within my org.
  i.e.
    List listOfThings = [Select Name From Object_Analysis__c]; or 
    List listOfThings = [Select Name From Naveen_catch__Object_Analysis__c];

or we can also write dynamic queries like this

```
List<SObject> listOfThings = Database.query('Select Name From Object_Analysis__c');
List<SObject> listOfThings = Database.query('Select Name From Naveen_catch__Object_Analysis__c');   .
```

All above queries will work successful.

PS : Someone asked this query in twitter , but I forgot who asked it. :)

Regards,
Niranjan,
Senior Program Architect, AutoRABIT.