# Create namespace for the code pushed from dev org to prod org

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, namespace

Currently I am developing in a fresh dev org with no namespace created. I want to push this code to another dev org with namespace already created. How I can push the code with namespace included( Both apex and lightning ). Do I need to change manually or any other ways available?

Answer (score 2):

You would push it just like normal. Changeset (not possible if orgs are not connected), IDE, ANT, etc.

Once it is in the org it will take on the namespace.

Are you running into any issues? If so please be more specific and you will get a more specific answer

**It all comes down to the basics, pushing code or metadata is no different than creating it manually.**

Comment: I can push the code using ANT tool. But Namespace is not created automatically. So, while packaging the test class throws error for field accessibility

Comment: Not to the code no, but to the field API names yes it will be. The code does not need it as everything in the org with the namespace is "local" despite the namespace. If you are packaging then when you package it will be added to the code

Comment: I tried packaging also (both beta and released), but no namespace is added to the code.

Comment: @scsiva1991 - It is in the package. Your local code will not be updated

Comment: it is in the package means, How can i check the namespace is added since we took managed package

Comment: Its *magic* - It just happens. Install your package and test it to see it work. Trust the process. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13353/dynamic-soql-queries-and-managed-namespaces

Comment: What makes you think it's _not_ being added?